# WCF Rest with basicHttpBinding on IIS 7.5 500 error

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5

yet another failed attempted to get a WCF Rest (no svc file) service using basicHttpBinding deployed to IIS 7.5. I believe I have the website configured properly along with IIS. I'm sure the problem resides in my config. The response I'm receiving is a 500 Error. I have a MVC 3 web running fine on this box.

The WCF Rest service is using basicHttpBinding with security mode of Transportcredentialonly. Here is my config;

```
    <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="AuthBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="NamedService">
        <endpoint contract="Namespace.IService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="AuthBinding"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Current web and IIS config based on other posts;

- I have a v4.0 app pool created for the web
- I have a website created associated with the above app pool
- I have both 32bit and 64bit .NET v4 ISAPI filters enabled
- I register v4 again with Aspnet_regiis.exe -i
- I have HTTP Redirect installed
- I have basic authentication enabled

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been at this for a day now. BTW... I'm not seeing any event messages. I know DNS is configured properly because I can strip away the WCF stuff and put a temp html page in the web and it works.

---------------- UPDATE ---------------------
Still having issues even after using this stripped down config. The couple things I left out is this is a x64 OS and I'm using castle as an IoC. I did run the Frameword64/aspnet_regiis.exe.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="castle" type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler, Castle.Windsor"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Main.ConnectionString" connectionString="data source=blah;initial catalog=newdatabase;User ID=web;Password=testing;persist security info=False;packet size=4096;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
   <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <castle>
    <properties>
      <myConnStr>data source=blah;initial catalog=newdatabase;User ID=web;Password=testing;persist security info=False;packet size=4096;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient</myConnStr>
    </properties>
    <components>
      <component id="RestService" service="Namespace.Rest.IRestService, Namespace.Rest" type="Namespace.Rest.RestService, Namespace.Rest" lifestyle="PerWebRequest"/>
      <component id="Repository" service="Namespace.Domain.Interfaces.IRepository, Namespace.Domain" type="Namespace.Domain.Repository, Thumbfound.Domain" lifestyle="PerWebRequest">
        <parameters>
          <connectionString>#{myConnStr}</connectionString>
        </parameters>
      </component>
    </components>
  </castle>
   <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <!-- 
            Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
            via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
        -->
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> yet another failed attempted to get a
>   WCF **Rest** (no svc file) service using
>   **basicHttpBinding** deployed to IIS 7.5.

There's your problem right there - WCF REST **must** use the `webHttpBinding` - **not** `basicHttpBinding` (that's a **SOAP** binding).

Comment: this didn't solve my issue. i actually stripped down my config so it mimics what the WCF 4 Rest template creates (webHttpBinding) by default. I still get a 500 error. Any further ideas?

Comment: @vince: 500 typically is an internal server error = error in your service code. You might need to debug into your service method to see what's happening

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was a Castle Windsor configuration issue.

The resolution to my problem was removing the `<httpmodules>` section within `<system.web>` and placing my PerRequestLifestyleModule config in the `<modules>` section of `<system.webServer>`. I guess IIS 7 doesn't like httpmodules in integrated mode.